# Does the 2GB database limitation in MS Access affect linked tables?

Tags: database, ms-access

I read that the Access database is limited to 2GB. If Access links to a table that is larger than 2GB, could the 2GB limitation still affect it? My gut feeling is no since they are two separate databases, but I'm concerned that Access was never intended to handle/work with databases larger than 2GB and might experience problems. Can anybody shed some light on this question?

Comment: Access 2016 will not link to an external file that exceeds 2GB, at least not a CSV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, linked tables do not use database space in Access database.

Comment: They only use space to describe the linkage information, but the data stored in the linked tables do not count toward this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx) regarding Access 2007+ databases:

> **Attribute** -- Total size for an Access 2010 database (.accdb), including all database objects and data
>
> **Maximum** -- 2 gigabytes, minus the space needed for system objects.
>
> > Note:  You can work around this size limitation by linking to tables in other Access databases. You can link to tables in multiple database files, each of which can be as large as 2GB.

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302524) page regarding earlier versions of Access makes no mention of linked tables, but it doesn't have the complete specification. The page references the built-in help in Access 2003.